# Django export filtered query to csv

Tags: python, django, csv

So the scenario is this: I have a search form where the user types or selects the criteria. These criteria are being posted and I get a query in returned, filtered with these criteria. The code for the search form is similar to the code shown below.

What I want to do now is take these results and export them in `csv` file. So, as I said I have almost the same code where I get my params/criteria with GET. Basically I GET the criteria the user has typed or selected after the search POST was made.

So far, I have succesfully got the params, I can see them in print, and the export is down but I can see only the first row. It's like I can't pass the query (as provided in results).

Here's my code:

```
    def get_csv(request):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=mycsv.csv'
        if request.method == 'GET':
            params = {}
            your_values = {}
            context = {}
            field_1 = request.GET.get('field_1',None)
            field_2 = request.GET.get('field_2',None)
            field_3 = request.GET.get('field_3',None)
            if field_1:
                your_values['field_1'] = field_1
            if field_2:
                your_values['field_2'] = field_2
            if field_3:
                your_values['field_3'] = field_3
            if field_4:
                your_values['field_4'] = field_4
            for key, value in your_values.items():
                if value:
                    params[key] = value
                print('params are:',params)
            results = Model.objects.filter(**params)
            writer = csv.writer(response)
            writer.writerow([h for h in [
                'Header_1',
                'Header_2',
                'Header_3',
                'Header_4',
                ]])
          #I tried that as well:writer.writerows([r for r in[results]])
            for field in results:
                field_list = [
                field.filed_1,
                field.field_2,
                field.field_3,
                field.field_4,
               ]
            for i, item in enumerate(field_list):
                if item:
                    field_list[i] = item
                    writer.writerow(field_list)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre seeing only one row because youre passing only one row:

```
for field in results:
     field_list = [
     field.filed_1,
     field.field_2,
     field.field_3,
     field.field_4,
     ]
```

The above puts only the item from the last iteration in `field_list` and the previous results are thrown away.

You can instead use a *list comprehension* to create the list of lists adding the indices at the same time using `enumerate`. And then write all the rows at the same time using `writerows`:

```
results = Model.objects.filter(**params)
writer = csv.writer(response)
writer.writerow(['Header_1', 'Header_2', 'Header_3', 'Header_4'])     
field_list = [[i, f.field_1, f.field_2, f.field_3, f.field_4] 
                         for i, f in enumerate(results) if f]
writer.writerows(field_list)
#              ^ notice the s
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work :( I still see only the frst row I pass

Comment: Are you using `writerows` with *plural s* or youre patching this with your original code?

Comment: How do you mean? Try printing `results` to confirm that.

Comment: print(results) returns [ ] 
print(csv_params) though returns the params

Comment: Thank you for your time Mores, yours was the "correctiest" answer. The problem is that the params are not passed in the query!!

Comment: @DanaeVogiatzi You're welcome. Glad you figured out the problem